# UIScrollView does not work when displaying photo from camera, but does from library

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a question regarding interesting behavior that I have on a UIScrollView. Here is the relevant code.

```
class TipCreationViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contView: UIView!

    var iView: UIImageView?
    var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: self.currentHeight)
        }
    }

    private var imageAttached: UIImage?
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false        
        self.currentHeight = 150
    }

    @IBAction func cameraWasPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        let actionFromLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "From Library", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        let actionFromCamera = UIAlertAction(title: "From Camera", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertViewController.addAction(actionFromLibrary)
        alertViewController.addAction(actionFromCamera)
        if imageAttached != nil {
            let actionDeletePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Remove Image", style: .Default, handler: { (_) -> Void in
                self.deletePhotoIfThere()
            })
            alertViewController.addAction(actionDeletePhoto)
        }
        alertViewController.addAction(actionCancel)
        alertViewController.view.tintColor = SHREDLIGHTS_BLUE
        self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //THIS SEEMS TO BE THE FUNCTION IN QUESTION...
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            deletePhotoIfThere()
            self.imageAttached = pickedImage
            let height = self.view.frame.width * pickedImage.scale
            self.iView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.currentHeight, self.contView.frame.width, height))
            self.iView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            self.iView!.image = pickedImage
            self.currentHeight += height
            self.contView.addSubview(self.iView!)
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func deletePhotoIfThere() {
        if let iv = self.iView {
            self.currentHeight -= iv.frame.height
            iv.removeFromSuperview()
            self.iView?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.iView = nil
        }
    }
}
```

So, the way that this works is that the user hits the `cameraWasPressed` button. This displays an action sheet that will allow the user to choose if they want to take a photo or pick one from their library. Now, the problems that I think I have is with `imagePickerController` method. All works as I expect. An image view is appended to the `contView` and the `currentHeight` will increase when the user picks a photo from the camera or from the library. Except one interesting piece of behavior. When the user takes a picture from the camera, the scroll view that I have freezes. However, when the user picks a picture from the library, the scroll view will work. Does anybody know why this discrepancy in regards to why a photo from the camera will cause a `UIScrollView` to stop working and one from the library will not cause any problems?